# adding a plot to a tab with qt

Tags: python, qt

I have a python gui in qt. the gui is buit using designer. It contains tabs. I want to add a plot. 
My plot object is a class (called MyPlot) that inherits from QtCore.QObject. To add it to the gui, I can simply do inside my class MainWindow that inherits from QtGui.QMainWindow:

```
self.Myplot(self)
self.MyPlot.plot()
```

But I don't know how to tell python to put the plot only in one tab. I suppose I have to do inside MainWindow something like:

```
self.tab(0).Myplot(self)
```

But I can't find exactly what.
Someone has any clue?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Trying to have a tab that reads an ui file generated by designer in the following code fails (I am just trying to put in a tab the things I build with designer, not to add a plot yet):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic


class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    uic.loadUi('mainwindow.ui', self)


class TabWidget(QtGui.QTabWidget):  
  def __init__(self, parent=None):  
    super (TabWidget, self).__init__(parent)  
    self.setTabsClosable(True)  
    self.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.removeTab)
    self.inside = MyWidget()

  def tabInserted(self, index):  
    self.tabBar().setVisible(self.count() > 1)  

  def tabRemoved(self, index):  
    self.tabBar().setVisible(self.count() > 1) 


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self,parent=None):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)


def main():
  qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  

  tab = TabWidget()  

  button = QtGui.QPushButton('Hello')  
  @button.clicked.connect  
  def clicked():  
    tab.addTab(QtGui.QLabel('Hello'), 'Hello')  

  tab.addTab(button, 'Button')  

  layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()  
  layout.addWidget(tab)  

  window = QtGui.QWidget()  
  window.setLayout(layout)  
  window.resize(600, 400)  
  window.show()  

  qApp.exec_()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: >My plot object is a class (called MyPlot) that inherits from QtCore< QtCore is a module, are you sure your class inherits it?

Comment: To put something to a form, it must be a [`QWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QWidget.html) subclass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way to use `QTabWidget` is to do the following:

1. Create a `QTabWidget`.
2. Create a `QWidget` for each of the pages in the tab dialog, but do not specify parent widgets for them.
3. Insert child widgets into the page widget, using layouts to position them as normal.
4. Call `addTab()` or `insertTab()` to put the page widgets into the tab widget, giving each tab a suitable label with an optional keyboard shortcut.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtabwidget.html#details

UPDATE:

I created a file `untitled.ui` in Qt Designer with a single checkbox. I also added call to parent `__init__` in `MyWidget`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic


class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
    uic.loadUi('untitled.ui', self)


class TabWidget(QtGui.QTabWidget):  
  def __init__(self, parent=None):  
    super (TabWidget, self).__init__(parent)  
    self.setTabsClosable(True)  
    self.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.removeTab)
    self.inside = MyWidget()

  def tabInserted(self, index):  
    self.tabBar().setVisible(self.count() > 1)  

  def tabRemoved(self, index):  
    self.tabBar().setVisible(self.count() > 1) 


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self,parent=None):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)


def main():
  qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  

  tab = TabWidget()  

  button = QtGui.QPushButton('Hello')  
  @button.clicked.connect  
  def clicked():  
    tab.addTab(QtGui.QLabel('Hello'), 'Hello')  

  tab.addTab(button, 'Button')  

  layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()  
  layout.addWidget(tab)  

  window = QtGui.QWidget()  
  window.setLayout(layout)  
  window.resize(600, 400)  
  window.show()  

  qApp.exec_()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

And it works.

Comment: Yes it seems to be the way but for now I dont manage to integrate the .ui generated by designer into my QTabWidget... Basically the method uic.loadUi("file.ui",self) fails inside the __init__ of the QTabWidget